# 70s (or earlier) YA novel with lizard people and vessels that burrow deep into the Earth's mantle

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I remember reading this ca. 1974. It was a YA novel in English that I got from my school library. They had a mass-market paperback copy. Unfortunately my memory is extremely sketchy, since it was a long time ago, and I was a little kid.

I remember two main things in the book that excited my imagination:

- There are lizard-like intelligent bipeds.
- There are machines sort of like underground submarines, or Mole Man's vehicle in the Marvel universe. They burrow deep underground, I think all the way down into the Earth's mantle. I think a lot of the plot involves people chasing each other underground in these vehicles, or racing against time.

Comment: Did the underground people build with diamond?

Comment: @AntonSherwood: I don't remember that, but my memory is very faded after 45 years :-) I actually don't remember if the lizard people lived underground, although that would make sense.

Comment: @AntonSherwood I was going to suggest the same book, but have blanked out on the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [*Stranger from the Depths*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2349510.Stranger_from_the_Depths) (1967) by Gerry Turner.

[image: Book cover showing a green humanoid with webbed hands and bulging eyes swimming in psychedelic looking water]

The lizard people lived in underground cities.

They traveled between their cities with an underground vehicle. (I can't remember if it was like a subway or a digging machine)

They used synthetic diamonds in much of their construction, for example the dome over the city, and a small (one foot?) statue of a lizard man.

The story begins with a group of teens/young adults finding a diamond lizard statue after an earthquake. Later, exploring the area, they wake up a lizard man from stasis pod. He had been in there a VERY long time. He leads them to his city, but it's deserted so they travel to another city trying to find answers.

Comment: That's it, instantly recognized the cover -- thanks! I'll award the bounty when the UI lets me. Wow, copies are not to be had at any reasonable price. Obviously many others liked this book as kids.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be *At the Earth's Core* (1914) by Edgar Rice Burroughs?

I have not read it, but in [Wikipedia's description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_the_Earth%27s_Core_(novel)), a miner named David Innes has an experimental excavating vehicle called an "iron mole".

There is a problem with the vehicle and they end up burrowing 500 miles into the Earth's crust and discover a land underneath -- a kind of hollow Earth -- called Pellucidar.

It has several different kinds of creatures, including the Mahars, which are intelligent flying reptiles.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the book I had in mind.

Comment: I have read both (many years apart!).  In the Burroughs, there is no “earth's mantle”.

Comment: @AntonSherwood call it what you like, but 500 miles in passes the crust and enters the mantle :-)  So even if the earth has a hollow area for Pellucidar, some part of the mantle is there.  But I can't argue with the fact that the OP says it's a different book....